# if .net standard is an specification, like an interface, how I set the implementation to use?

Tags: c#, .net

When I asked about the difference between .net Standard and .net Core, I have clear that .net standard is like an interface and .net Core is like a class that implements the interface .net Standard.

My question now is, when I create a .net standard library, that is an interface, when I build and use this library in a WPF project for example, how could I know what implementation of .net Standard I am using? because it could be .net Core o another different implementation, perhaps .net framework (ok, perhaps in the future version 2.0 of .net Standard, not now).

Thanks.

Comment: When they use "interface" and "implementation" to tell the differences between .NET Standard and .NET Core, your understanding is far from the truth. .NET Standard defines a set of APIs on paper, while .NET Core or .NET Framework is the runtime that enables such APIs. So if your library is compiled against .NET Standard API profile, it would work fine on all runtimes that support the API profile. Try some sample projects to feel it, and don't be puzzled by words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.NET Standard` is the "interface" which is used by your library. When you create a ".NET Standard Library", your code in that library is using the "interface". Among others, `.NET Core` or `.NET Framework` are implementing the "interface". That allows your library to run on both of them.

Do not be confused by the project template ".NET Standard Library". That is a template not for a library which is part of the .NET Standard but for a library which uses the `.NET Standard`.